# Grouping CASE results in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a linked list setup from a root node, which links up different item types. To retrieve say the first 10 items (with possible relationships), I am doing the following:

```
START user=node(1)
MATCH user-[:LIST*1..10]->item
WITH item
MATCH author-[a?:AUTHOR]->item
RETURN item, a, author
```

This works fine and returns the desired items, however there are some author properties I don't want to return to the client. So normally I would only `RETURN` the desired properties, eg. `RETURN author.name, author.location`, but this won't work if the item does not have an author. I can use `?` on the properties, but then I would potentially end up with a lot of null properties for each item.

Then I found the `CASE` statement, and it almost works for my use case. The problem is I would like to be able to return multiple properties per `THEN` if possible. For example:

```
RETURN labels(item) as type,
CASE HEAD(type) 
    WHEN "Post" THEN (item.title, item.text, author)
    WHEN "Message" THEN (item.subject, item.content)
END as item
```

The `WHEN` lines above will return a syntax error because you can only put a single value after THEN. Is there any way to combine results into an object like the way above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a literal collection after the then, we will add map support in the future, so it will get even nicer :)

You can also change head(type) to item:Label

```
RETURN labels(item) as type,
CASE 
    WHEN item:Post THEN [item.title, item.text, author]
    WHEN item:Mesage THEN [item.subject, item.content]
END as item
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add for those landing here on grouping or building results from a CASE WHEN..

You can also build a hash or object based collection (from Michael Hunger example)...

```
RETURN labels(item) as type,
CASE 
    WHEN item:Post THEN {title: item.title, text: item.text, author:author}
    WHEN item:Mesage THEN {subject:item.subject, content:item.content}
END as item
```

Where `author` in this case might have been built from a previous `collect({..})`.

WARNING HOWEVER: do not attempt a collect() after a THEN, Neo4j will go into a wild spin (only tested on 2.0.0) and crash, maybe recover if your lucky..

DO NOT DO:

```
 WHEN item:Post THEN collect({title: item.title, text: item.text, author:author})
```

This sounded normal to me, but the one without collect works as well, if someone could explain it would help get a better understanding of collect and CASE WHEN..

Meanwhile, Cypher on..